# Verify private static method on final class gets called using PowerMockito

Tags: java, powermockito

I have the following class

```
public final class Foo {
  private Foo() {}
  public static void bar() {
    if(baz("a", "b", new Object())) { }
  }
  private static boolean baz(Object... args) {
    return true;  // slightly abbreviated logic
  }
}
```

And this is my Test:

```
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest(Foo.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
  @Test
  public void bar() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class); // prepare
    Foo.bar(); // execute
    verifyPrivate(Foo.class, times(1)).invoke("baz", anyVararg()); // verify - fails
  }
}
```

For that, I get the following error message - and I don't understand why...

> Wanted but not invoked com.example.Foo.baz(
>       null );
>
> However, there were other interactions with this mock.

Removing the `prepare` line above seems to make the verify line pass no matter for how many `times` you check for... :(

(Our SONAR code checks enforce that each test has some sort of `assertXyz()` in it (hence the call to `verify()`) and enforces a very high test coverage.)

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to mock the static method instead of just verifying it works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you **mock** `Foo` so your method implementations won't be called by default such that when you call `Foo.call()`  it does nothing by default which means that it never avtually calls `baz` that is why you get this behavior. If you want to **partially mock** `Foo`, mock it using the option  `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` in order to make it call the real methods as you seem to expect, so the code should be:

```
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest(Foo.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void bar() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS); // prepare
        ...
    }
}
```